# How to correctly import latest libarchive for use on Mac OS

Tags: python, libarchive

The [release notes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libarchive) for libarchive state that because of an older version of libarchive being included within MacOS they recommend changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point towards the location of the recent copy of libarchive.

I've used this code to try and achieve that but I get an error message when I run the script.

```
import os

print os.environ.get('LD_LIBRARY_PATH') #Check what the current path is 

os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/'
print os.environ.get('LD_LIBRARY_PATH') #Check the variable has been set 

import libarchive.public
```

Error:

```
None
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch.py", line 8, in <module>
    import libarchive.public
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libarchive/public.py", line 1, in <module>
    from libarchive.adapters.archive_read import \
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libarchive/adapters/archive_read.py", line 7, in <module>
    import libarchive.calls.archive_read
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libarchive/calls/archive_read.py", line 17, in <module>
c_archive_read_support_filter_all = libarchive.archive_read_support_filter_all
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fb08b741000, archive_read_support_filter_all): symbol not found
```

I cant find a great answer to this anywhere out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear from the tool documentation, but based on a thread: https://github.com/dsoprea/PyEasyArchive/issues/16 I set another environment variable to the place where the underlying c library could be found. In my case, it was put there by homebrew on my mac.

```
os.environ['LA_LIBRARY_FILEPATH']='/usr/local/opt/libarchive/lib/libarchive.dylib'

import libarchive.public
```

worked for me.